# Mockito asks to add @PrepareForTest for the class even after adding @PrepareForTest

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have the following simple code. I have a class (TestClass) and I want to test "someMethod". There is an external static method which is called by my "someMethod". 
I want to Powermock that static method to return me some dummy object.
I have the @PrepareForTest(ExternalClass.class) in the begining, but when I execute it gives the error:

*The class ExternalClass not prepared for test.
To prepare this class, add class to the `'@PrepareForTest'` annotation.
In case if you don't use this annotation, add the annotation on class or  method level.*

Please help me to point out what is wrong with the way I have used `@PrepareForTest`

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ExternalClass.class)
public class xyzTest {  
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private TestClass testClass;

    @BeforeClass
    private void setUpBeforeClass() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuccessCase() {
        Boolean mockResponse = true;
        ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(mockResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass("test", "1.0.0", "someUrl", "someMetaData");

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ExternalClass.class);

        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(String.class), any(String.class), eq(Boolean.class))).thenReturn(response);
        Mockito.when(ExternalClass.getSomeClass(any(String.class))).thenReturn(someClass);

        Boolean result = testClass.someMethod("test");

        Assert.isTrue(result);
        Mockito.verify(restTemplate, times(1)).postForObject(any(String.class), any(String.class), any());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're running this class on JUnit4 in a desktop JVM, right? And ExternalClass is _not_ a Java system class?

Comment: Yes, I'm running it on desktop JVM (Oracle, 1.8). And ExternalClass is a custom Java Class (NOT Java system class: i.e. java*.*)

Comment: I see you're using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(...)` along with using the Powermock JUnit Runner.  This is unnecessary.  The Powermock runner will setup your mocks.  I don't know if this will help your situation, because I'm having the same problem and I am not making an additional call to initialize mocks.

Comment: For me it works just fine. What Mockito & Powermockito versions are you using?

Comment: You should definitely check your imports as @Dan suggested. But you might also have an initialization problem caused by `@BeforeClass` annotation being applied to a non static method `setUpBeforeClass`.

Comment: I think you ca find the respononse of the problem in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966897/powermock-java-11

Comment: I think you ca find the respononse of the problem in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966897/powermock-java-11

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Make sure you add `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` to the top of your class as well.

**::edit:: two years later...**

Don't ever use PowerMockito, you shouldn't need to.

If you do need to, you have most likely broken the SOLID principles and your design is wrong.

Fix your design instead.

Comment: And delegate it to the springrunner so that you can integrate it with spring boot;

@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)

Comment: This answer is not helpful. Even if MOST of the time you should not mock static methods, converting a static method to instance method (1) may not be possible if you don't own that code and (2) may make the code more error-prone. The most likely outcome of not mocking status is not writing tests against code that calls static methods. And that's much worse.

Comment: I agree much with @Vroo. I am right in front of such a case where so-called SOLID principles are happily violated by Apache! I have been breaking my head for two days now, on this thing. Too bad that this answer has become a top hit in SO...

Comment: So we should add wrappers to all static methods we use? That doesn't make any sense because they exist to be used

Comment: @Goldname don't use static methods.

Comment: @wild_nothing so one would need to go through the roundabout way of instantiating a class for the sole purpose of running a simple function in java? Why then do standard java classes have static methods to them?

Answer (score 18):

As with the last answer, my problem was also mixing the Test annotation from TestNG instead of Junit Test.

```
import org.junit.Test; // works

import org.testng.annotations.Test // did not work
```

Very abstruse error and I spent more than 5 hrs debugging :(

Comment: This is the answer that helped me! Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

For those trying to get this working with Junit 5, If your using the `powermock-module-junit4` beta release which claims to be compatible with 4+, the library will still not recognize:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

and it will throw a:

```
org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException
```

when `@PrepareForTest` is applied on the class you want to static mock. If you want to use PowerMock, you will have to go back to Junit 4 or create a MockWrapper for your static method at this time.

PowerMock 2.0: [Github Roadmap](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/725)

Answer (score 12):

While the top-rated answer here is correct without a doubt, this does not answer the question of *why* is that needed; or, for example, why the same thing would not work with adding `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

The thing is `PowerMockRunner` uses instrumentation API under the hood, via 
[javassist](https://www.javassist.org/) library, this allows to alter the classes, like remove `final` or mock `static` (non-compile time constants).

In the process of modifying (instrumenting) a certain class, they add an interface to that, called `PowerMockModified`. It is a marker interface that denotes that a certain byte-code instrumentation took place. Later in the code, they simply check if the class that you use in `@PrepareForTest` was actually instrumented in some way or not, via such a method:

```
    private boolean isModifiedByPowerMock() {
        return PowerMockModified.class.isAssignableFrom(this.type);
    }
```

In turns out that `PowerMockRunner` *does* some instrumentation, while `MockitoJUnitRunner` does not; thus the error you get.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error, resolved this by adding

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```

inside the test class.

Answer (score 5):

check if import org.junit.Test; package has imported and not that api jupiter one.

Answer (score 3):

If above answers don't work try `extends PowerMockTestCase`. This trick worked for me.

Example:
`public class xyzTest extends PowerMockTestCase`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but resolved it. My problem was that I included `powermock-module-junit4` but included my test annotation from TestNG instead of Junit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I was using TestNG to run the tests. I had to use the following method to fix the above issue.

```
@ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For testNG there are 2 options as follows :

1. Using ObjectFactory as below:

```java
    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }
```

2. Test class extending `extends org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase`

Answer (score 0):

My gradle was using Junit 5.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I was able to debug this. By having breakpoints in PowerMockRunner methods.
It was not invoked. Moreover JUnit 5 is not supported with PowerMockito.

Looks like JUnit5 runs without @ExtendWith.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using **powermock2**. I had this problem when I was using **powermock**.
Use

```
import org.powermock2.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
```