# PowerMockito ClassNotPreparedException

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have the following jars:

```
javax.servlet-api-3.1.9.jar
junit-4.10.jar
mockito-all-1.10.19.jar
mockito-core-1.10.19.jar
powermock-api-mockito-1.6.5.jar
powermock-api-mockito-common-1.6.5.jar
powermock-api-support-1.6.5.jar
powermock-core-1.6.5.jar
powermock-module-junit4-1.6.5.jar
powermock-reflect-1.6.5.jar
```

I want to test this method called `createPanel` which is inside a class called `Controller`:

```
public static void createPanel(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, HttpSession hs) throws IOException
{
    PanelManager.createPanel(req, res, hs);
}
```

In the `ControllerTest` class (junit tester), I have this:

```
 import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
 import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
 import org.junit.Test;
 import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
 import org.mockito.Mockito;
 import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
 import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
 import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
 import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
 import ApplicationLogic.Controller;
 import ApplicationLogic.PanelManager;
 import ApplicationLogic.RegistrationManager;
 import ApplicationLogic.SessionManager;

 @PrepareForTest(PanelManager.class)
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

 public class ControllerTest {

     Controller controller = Mockito.mock(Controller.class);

     SessionManager sessionManager = Mockito.mock(SessionManager.class);

     RegistrationManager registrationManager =  Mockito.mock(RegistrationManager.class);
      .
      .
      .
      .

  @Test

 public void testcreatePanel() throws ServletException, IOException{

    HttpServletRequest req = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse res = Mockito.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    HttpSession hs = Mockito.mock(HttpSession.class);


    //PowerMockito.mock(SessionManager.class);

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("somefile.txt");
    when(res.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Controller.class);

    PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(controller).createPanel(req, res, hs);
```

All the tests for the other methods in the controller class are running fine. Why it is causing this error at `PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod()`:

```
org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException: 
The class ApplicationLogic.Controller not prepared for test.
To prepare this class, add class to the '@PrepareForTest' annotation.
In case if you don't use this annotation, add the annotation on class or  method level. 

    at org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.reporter.MockitoPowerMockReporter.classNotPrepared(MockitoPowerMockReporter.java:31)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockTypeValidatorFactory$DefaultMockTypeValidator.validate(MockTypeValidatorFactory.java:38)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.AbstractMockCreator.validateType(AbstractMockCreator.java:18)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMock(MockCreator.java:57)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:47)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:71)
    at JUnitTest.ControllerTest.testcreatePanel(ControllerTest.java:253)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55731988/1059372)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `PowerMockRunner` instead of the `MockitoJUnitRuner`.

This example addresses the `ClassNotPreparedException`:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({PanelManager.class})
public class ControllerTest {

    Controller controller = Mockito.mock(Controller.class);

    @Test
    public void testcreatePanel() throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest req = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse res = Mockito.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        HttpSession hs = Mockito.mock(HttpSession.class);

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("somefile.txt");
        Mockito.when(res.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(PanelManager.class);
        PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(controller).createPanel(req, res, hs);
    }
}
```

However, it looks like there might still be some issues even after that;  you are mocking Controller and then treating it as a partial mock by invoking `doCallRealMethod()` on it. Perhaps there is a genuine reason for this (maybe that reason would be revealed by showing more of your code) but if you do not have a genuine reason for that then you could remove this line:

```
Controller controller = Mockito.mock(Controller.class);
```

And replace this line ...

```
PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(controller).createPanel(req, res, hs);
```

with this:

```
Controller.createPanel(req, res, hs);
```

This would then allow you to mock the behaviour of `PanelManager` and test the *actual* behaviour of `Controller` in response to the `PanelManager`'s mocked behaviour.

Comment: Thanks I just saw your response right now. So why would that work? Because I'm not using 'doCallRealMethod()', it doesnt matter?

Comment: @Lazaro you asked "why would that work?" I'm not sure what "that" is referring to. In my answer this part: "use the PowerMockRunner instead of the MockitoJUnitRuner" fixes the ClassNotPreparedException. The other suggestion in my answer avoids using "PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod()" at all and instead using a real Controller instance.

Comment: @glytching *You have to use the PowerMockRunner instead of the MockitoJUnitRuner* - though this _is_ correct, it does not explain _why_

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're missing the `PowerMockRule` declaration:

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```

Also, keep in mind that you should let Powermock know that it shouldn't load mockito classes to the system class loader. Add the following code at the top of your class:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*"})
```

Your class declaration should look like this:

```
@PrepareForTest(PanelManager.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*"})
public class ControllerTest {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
    //...
}
```

Comment: This was unfortunately at no help when using Junit 5 and Powermockito 2+. Any other suggestions?