# How to mock a static method in JUnit 5

Tags: junit, junit5

I am upgrading my JUnit to version 5 and I get this error when I run the JUnit 5

I am using in my pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException:
>
> [Ljava.lang.Object;@723ca036 The class com.xxxxxx.MyClass not prepared
>   for test.

I am using `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` for my class test notation

My code is

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
when(MyClass.get(anyString()))
    .thenReturn(mock);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powermock throws ClassNotPreparedException when using JUnit 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779581/powermock-throws-classnotpreparedexception-when-using-junit-5)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **ExtendWith**. In junit 5 the annotation gets @RunWith changed to

@ExtendWith(JUnitPlatform.class)

[Further details on how to use Extend with](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-junit-5-extension)