# Upgrade Java 8 to 11 powermock issue

Tags: java, maven-plugin, powermockito, maven-surefire-plugin, java-11

I am using surifire, failsafe, mockito and powermock. Where ever I tried I got like power mock is not support for Java 11.

I have tried with the latest version of surefire also but it throws exception like. (build success if I skip the test cases)

> Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR! org.objenesis.ObjenesisException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class
>   jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl loaded by
>   org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader @77cf3f8b cannot access
>   jdk/internal/reflect superclass jdk.internal.reflect.MagicAccessorImpl

Which version will resolve this issue? In order to support Java 11, `maven-compiler-plugin 3.6.0`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966897/powermock-java-11

Comment: So that will work for @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class).it need to be add as a separate statement right.

Comment: I have used like this

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.*"})

still I faces the same issue 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Did you fix it @VG__? Im on the same boat.

Comment: Not sure, but most searching says power mock no longer ( no newer versions) for java... java 11 we need to change some other  mocj like jmock.